# Hide DataGridView Columns

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I am currently using the `HeaderText` to show/hide columns in a `asp:GridView`

Well now I am in need of having no display text for the `HeaderText` so I am at a loss on how to refactor this syntax to show/hide columns based off the button click.

This is my current C# and HTML -> how would I alter it so that it will still work with no `HeaderText` value set?

```
   private int GetColumnIndex(GridView grid, string ColName)
{
    foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == ColName.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}       

protected void btnS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    var columnname = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cbxSponsorLevel.Items)
    {
        columnname = item.Text;
        var index = GetColumnIndex(GridView1, columnname);
        string number = index.ToString();
        if (index > 0)
        {
            GridView1.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
        }
    }
}

<div id="dgv">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Font-Size="9px" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Sport" HeaderText="Sport"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Event Number" HeaderText="Event"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Score" HeaderText="Score"> <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>        
</asp:GridView></div>
```

Comment: What is `btnS_Click` and please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a checkbox list and a button on my asp page.  The text for the checkbox list matches the text for the header.  If you check the checkbox for Sport, then click the button (btnS_Click()) gridview1 should be displayed showing Name and Sport (since the checkbox is checked)

Comment: How about retaining header text value but hiding from the view using css?

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran - I think that solution would work.  Just above my head coding wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden-field
        {
           display:none;
        }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sport" HeaderText="Sport" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-field">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: How is the `hidden-field` class being added to the tag?

Comment: HeaderStyle-CssClass attribute

Comment: But it has to be added from code behind dynamically and I dont see that.

Comment: That is not his requirement, he wants to use HeaderText value to control the visibility of a column but the HeaderText should not be displayed in the view.

Comment: Actually in the comment the OP mentioned he has a bunch of checkboxes that control whether the column should be shown or not. User checks the column and then clicks a button to show/hide columns. But the OP accepted your answer so I could be wrong.

Comment: I agree, check boxes control the visibility of the columns and that logic is implemented in the code-behind functions mentioned in the question. My answer is on how to manage the visibility of the header text without disturbing the logic.